# WCF with BasicAuthentification problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, basic-authentication

I hardly try to set up BasicAuthentification for my WCF (published on IIS 8.5). But i always get one of these Error:

> http request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'basic'. Got following authentificationheader "Digest qop="auth",algorithm=MD5-sess,nonce="someMD5stuff",charset=utf-8,realm="Digest",Negotiate,NTLM,Basic realm="localhost"" from the server.

or

> The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. Got authentificationheader "Basic realm="localhost"" from server.

My web.config serverside (in WCF):

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WCF_for_APP.Service1">
    <endpoint
      address=""
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      contract="WCF_for_APP.Service"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPersonService" />
    <binding>
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://somewhere/customerService"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPersonService"
    contract="PersonService.IPersonService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IPersonStateService" />
</client>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>        
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>  
      <serviceAuthenticationManager authenticationSchemes="Basic"></serviceAuthenticationManager>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
          customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="CustomerValidator.SecureBindingUsernamePasswordValidator, CustomerValidator" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.servicemodel>
```

I've tried it to set a name to the bindingConfiguration etc. but it didn't change a thing.

I try to access my WCF via Channelfactory clientside in an ASP Application:

```
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(endpointadress);

BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
basicHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = Int16.MaxValue;
basicHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
basicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;

ChannelFactory<Service> channelFactory = null;
Service client = null;            

channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<Service>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);
channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wcfUser"].ToString();
channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wcfPW"].ToString();
try
{
    client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
    string a = client.SendMail();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Response.Write(e.Message);
}
```

Basic authentication on IIS is activated. I really don't want to switch to HTTPS and certificates because i just need this basicauthent for internal security. I can't even start the WCF with the visual studio wcf testclient but everything works fine without the authentication settings.
Both, WCF and ASP, are published on my local IIS.

Any suggestions what the problem is? Do i have to add a user to my local system with same credentials?

** **EDIT** **

i guess i know the issue! In my WCF i make a call to another WCF (from customer) and this one in combination with my security settings is making troubles. so how do i solve this? My WCF with server side config and customert WCF with client side config in one web.config? (customer WCF is called via ChannelFactory too) Because if i name the bindingconfigs it doesn't change a thing (see code above).

Code for customer WCF call via ChannelFactory looks like the code above. 
Could this be the Problem? 2 WCF - one serverside and one for calls?!

Comment: Don't use BASIC without https. It is trivial to pull passwords off the wire with a sniffer. Don't think that internal only means "safe".

Comment: @Crowcoder - i really don't care if externals can see something. there's no intimate transfer going on. it's just to secure internal for every employee if they hit the site of the WCF erroneously.

Comment: @DaveStockinger did you try add realm to Credentials on client?

Comment: @mkysoft i just tried to add `localhost` in web.config of WCF but it didn't work either. and i didn't find a way to add a realm on client programmatically.

Comment: @DaveStockinger you can remove basic authentication and custom  validation config then enable only Basic authentication on IIS. Add user to web site folder at folder security tab. This is easy way. But every user can call web your web sevice who has authorization to site folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was fine with my BasicAuthentification.

The Error was the other WCF i'm calling via my WCF and because of security settings in my WCF i wasn't able to debug (not with hanging to process or testclient) and because of no details in the error message i didn't find the source of this error. This other WCF throws the Error with "Basic" isn't allowed so my customer did some changes on his IIS (maybe).

And i had to add a local user with the same credentials as i use in my WCF. Didn't know that but yeah - everything's good and i've to wait what my customer tells me about their settings.

Answer (score 0):

I create test project and it is working. Codes are below:

IService1 interface:

```
namespace WcfTestService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }


    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Service1 class:

```
namespace WcfTestService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
}
```

web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfTestService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="HttpBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding" contract="WcfTestService.IService1" />

      </service>

    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding"  >
          <readerQuotas />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">

            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" realm="" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="HttpBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Enable basic authentication on IIS, disable anonymous.

WCF Client console application:

```
namespace WcfTestClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(@"http://localhost/Service1.svc");

            BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            basicHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;

            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<WcfTestService.IService1>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);
            channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = @"server\someuser";
            channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = @"somepass";
            try
            {
                var client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
                string a = client.GetData(55);
                Console.Write(e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Download: http://sharesend.com/6gutdu4s

Comment: if i try to access my wcf via browser everything works perfectly. i'm asked for credentials and when i login i see the service BUT when i try to access it programmatically i still get the same error when it comes to `client.GetData()`.

Comment: i guess i know the issue! In my WCF i make a call to another WCF (from customer) and this one is in combination with my security settings is making troubles. so how do i solve this? My WCF with server side config and customert WCF with client side config in one web.config? (customer WCF is called via ChannelFactory too)

Comment: I tested it, it is working. I install service on different machine. Did you try same code?

Comment: everything's fine with my WCF. The second WCF i'm calling was offline and the Error Message i got was from this connection failure.
Thank you anyway!